# In python, how do you get the escape sequence for any Unicode character?

Tags: python, string, unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

In python, what is the escape sequence for the left-double quote Unicode character `“` (U+201C)?

```python
left_double_quote = "“"

print(ord(left_double_quote)) # prints `8220`
```

Note that `201C` is hexadecimal notation for the decimal number `8220`

I tried somethings, but it did not work:

```python
print("\x8220")
print("\x201C")
print("\0x201C")
```

Comment: In this specific case, `print("\u201C")`. It cannot use `\x` because that only accommodates two hex digits. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\u` escape to indicate you are specifying unicode bytes rather than hex (ASCII?) bytes.

So for your example, you can use this:

```
print("\u201c")

# output: “
```